# How to get month and week of the month from year and week no in R?

Tags: r, date

I have a column with year and week of the year.I need month and week no of the month from that column.Any help would be highly appreciated.

I have x,what I need is y and z.

```
x          y(month of the year)             z (week number of that month)
2016-11      3                                        3
2016-12      3                                        4
2018-01      1                                        1 
2019-10      3                                        2
```

This is what I tried

```
as.Date(paste(x,sep=""),"%Y%U%u")
```

Comment: Did you checkout `lubridate` functions like `week`, `month`?

Comment: yes I did,I am not able to get the expected result

Comment: What day do these year-week dates correspond to? Is it always the first day of that week? The last?

Comment: Its monday of every month

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(
        x = as.POSIXct(strptime(paste0(x, "-1"), format = "%Y-%W-%u")),
        y = format(x, "%m"),
        z = 1 + as.integer(format(x, "%d")) %/% 7)
#           x  y z
#1 2016-03-14 03 3
#2 2016-03-21 03 4
#3 2018-01-01 01 1
#4 2019-03-11 03 2
```

Note: This assumes that the `year-weekno` dates refer to the first day of every week.

---

Or in base R

```
transform(
    transform(df, x = as.POSIXct(strptime(paste0(x, "-1"), format = "%Y-%W-%u"))),
    y = format(x, "%m"),
    z = 1 + as.integer(format(x, "%d")) %/% 7)
#           x  y z
#1 2016-03-14 03 3
#2 2016-03-21 03 4
#3 2018-01-01 01 1
#4 2019-03-11 03 2
```

Comment: @pzhao I guess it boils down to personal preference. I usually prefer the `dplyr`/`tidyverse` syntax over base R. But I have added a base R only solution using `transform`.

Comment: Thanks. It should be noted that this solution is a mixture of week counting. %W uses Monday as the beginning of the week in the year, while %d / 7 uses the first day of the month as the beginning of the week in the month. The question itself does not define it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @maurits-evers is neat, while I rewrote it independently from `dplyr`:

```
x <- c('2016-11', '2016-12', '2018-01', '2019-10')
x2 <- strptime(paste(x, "1"), format = "%Y-%W %u")
yw <- data.frame(x = x,
                 y = as.integer(format(x2, '%m')),
                 z = as.integer(format(x2, "%d")) %/% 7 + 1
                 )
```